# GWT better a single service with all methods inside or more services

Tags: java, gwt

This project is something like StackOverflow.
We must write the project in GWT and i would like to know if it's better use a single service (like GreetingService) and put all methods inside it, user registration, user login, user post question, user answare.

Or it's better use a service for group...one service manage the user, one service manage the question and answere and one service manage categories of questions.

And if we divide it with more services they can communicate wichothers or need a "superservice" that manage everything?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the answer you're looking for, but I wanted to notice a *Command pattern*. The original presentation is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM&t=9m45s . This pattern had a great impact on the model of client-server interaction in my projects and I could always get away with only one service per module.

Comment: But yes, essentially in this 2009 presentation GWT team suggested to use a "superservice". I'm not aware of more modern approaches related to this particular subject.